# Using PHP curl to run a PUT command on a zip file on PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, curl

Hi I need to perform this PUT command in PHP using curl but I'm having issues getting it to run. The file that needs to be transferred is a zip file. This is the curl command:

curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/zip" --data-binary @yZip.zip http://183.262.144.266:1211/y-validation/repository/HELLO

This is the code I have so far

```
$ch = curl_init();
$filepath = 'yZip.zip';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://183.262.144.266:1211/y-validation/repository/HELLO');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
$fh_res = fopen($filePath, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
$curl_response = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($curl_response);
```

I've taken this code from various websites but I keep getting errors and not sure what to do next any ideas?

**UPDATED: Fixed the errors and I am linking the REST API successfully but the zip file is not being uploaded correctly.**

**UPDATED 2: Updated with code changes I've made since to try and solve problem but the zip is still not being PUT correctly. Also I'm working on PHP 5.3.8 so can't use the CurlFile class. Can anyone help with this?**

**UPDATED 3: Still having problems with this, trying to implement headers but thats not working either can anyone help me out?**

Comment: Maybe tell us exactly what errors you get?

Comment: hey check this one https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

Comment: Hi, the issue now is the zip file is not being PUT correctly. It is PUT into the repository I am accessing but it is empty so I must be doing something wrong with the zip file before I make the transfer.

Comment: Are you `fopen`ing the correct file? Does `var_dump($fh_res)` and `var_dump(filesize($filePath))` give the expected result?

Comment: Ya seems to be opening the correct file, the results I get from var_dump on those is: "resource(87) of type (stream)" , 
"int(38664)"

Comment: Still having issues with this, please see update 3 can anyone help me out?its pretty urgent

Answer (score 0):

I try this code and make work it for me...

```
 <?php
 set_time_limit(600);
$ch = curl_init();
$filePath = 'file.zip';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site/reciver_script_name/uploading/path/name');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
$fh_res = fopen($filePath, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/zip'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
$curl_response = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($curl_response);

?>
```

And receiver side:

some path tips...

```
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
if (substr($path, 0, strlen($prefix)) != $prefix) {
    exit_not_found();
}
$path = substr($path, strlen($prefix));
$parts = explode('/', $path);
if (!is_array($parts) || count($parts) != 3) {
    exit_not_found();
}
```

and main part...

```
if (!$error) {
    $file_stream = fopen($file, 'w');
    if ($file_stream === false) {
        $error = 'fopen failed';
    }
}
if (!$error) {
    $copy_result = stream_copy_to_stream(fopen('php://input', 'r'), $file_stream);
    fclose($file_stream);
    if (!$copy_result) {
        $error = 'stream_copy_to_stream failed';
    }
}
```